# OnEdit select just a few cells or small range

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

is their a better way of doing this??? This is working fine for 3 cells, but If i want this to run on a larger group of cells this is silly. Would a named range work? Could someone show me some examples? Thanks

```
function onEdit(e) {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Loads");


  if (e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() != "Loads" || e.range.columnStart != 1 || e.range.rowStart != 51)
  if (e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() != "Loads" || e.range.columnStart != 1 || e.range.rowStart != 52)
  if (e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() != "Loads" || e.range.columnStart != 1 || e.range.rowStart != 53)
      return;

///run function here

};
```

Comment: This code looks like nonsense to me. There is no range property columnStart or rowStart so obviously you haven't tested your code.  What is your question?

Comment: "is their a better way of doing this???"  is not a clear question. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve]

Comment: @cooper It actually works perfectly. Do you have experience with onEdit events in Google apps script?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is what you were shooting for:

```
function onEdit(e) {

  var name=e.source.getActiveSheet().getName();
  var col=e.range.getColumn();
  var row=e.range.getRow();

  if (name=="Loads" && col==1 && row >= 51 && row<=53)
  {  
     //run function here
  }
}
```

Comment: This is along the lines of what I was looking for. I'll test this along with my script.